# Як правильно писати "инший" чи "інший"?

Tags: правопис

**Инший**
Таке слово є у [словнику](http://hrinchenko.com/slovar/znachenie-slova/21407-ynshyj.html), який склав  Борис Грінченко. Цей словник не містить варіанту "інший".

**Інший**
є на
[wiktionary](https://uk.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%96%D0%BD%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B9), де нема "инший";

є в словнику [СУМ-11](http://sum.in.ua/s/inshyj), де нема "инший".

То ж як слід писати?